# How to send a single message to multi connections using UE?

Tags: unificationengine

I have tried to send messages to various connections via unification engine and it works fine. It's mentioned here (https://developer.unificationengine.com/) that its possible to send only one message to unification engine mentioning  various connections and it sends it to respective social media apps. However, I am not able to find a way to get it to work. Please advise if anyone has tried.

Appreciate your help!

Thanks & Best Regards,
Anand Patil

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to send same message to multiple connections via unification engine. 
The following command will send the same messsage to two facebook connections and a twitter connection

curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/message/send --data "{ \"message\": { 
\"receivers\": [

{\"name\": \"Me\", \"address\": \"\"  , \"Connector\": \"UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER_FACEBOOK_1\"},

{\"name\": \"Me\", \"address\": \"\"  , \"Connector\": \"UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER_FACEBOOK_2\"},

{\"name\": \"name\", \"address\": \"TWITTER_HANDLE\"  , \"Connector\": \"UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER_TWITTER_1\"}

],

\"parts\":

[{\"id\": \"1\",\"contentType\": \"text/plain\", \"data\":\"MESSAGE_BODY\" ,\"size\": MESSAGE_BODY_SIZE,\"type\": \"body\",\"sort\":0}]

}}" -u USER_ACCESSKEY:USER_ACCESSSECRET -k